# New Proof System

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I've been going on past homework and I've faced a question that seems a little bit illogical to me or that it's too simple. Here is the question:

***Question:*** Let N be a new semantic proof system which has the Axioms:

1. $A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow A)$
2. $(A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow ((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))$
3. $(\neg B\rightarrow\neg A)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow B)$

And one derive law (called NMP) is:

- $\frac{(A\rightarrow B),(B\rightarrow C)}{(A\rightarrow C)}$

The derive law is actually the transitive relation. We're required to prove or disprove the below statements:

1. $\gamma\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\vdash_N\alpha\rightarrow\gamma$
2. $\vdash_N(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)\rightarrow(\gamma\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta))$
3. If $\vdash_N \alpha$ then $\vdash_{CPL}\alpha$
4. If $T\vdash_N\alpha$ then $T\vdash_{CPL}\alpha$

***What I think:*** I think that without any assumptions we can't use NMP at all, therefore we can tell that 1, 2, 4 are false and only 3 is true.

Comment: I think you're wrong but I don't know what CPL is, nor am I sure whether "T" is a special symbol of the language or not. However, I think that you can prove (2) in the system N by using Ax 3 with the obvious choices, Axiom 1 with the choice $A=(\alpha\to\beta), B=\gamma$ and then using rule NMP.

Comment: @ancientmathematician - $T$ is a set of assumptions and CPL is (presumably) Classical Propositional Logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I thought it mattered which version of CPL we were using, but on reflection think that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 'ancient mathematician' and 'Bram28' I got my answer to the question and here I post it:

**1. The claim is false.**

In 3 we prove that the system is sound therefore if $\gamma\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\vdash_N(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)$ **then** $\gamma\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\vdash_{CPL}(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)$. If we define a valuation $\alpha=t,\beta=t,\gamma=f$ then $\gamma\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$ is **true** but $(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)$ is **false**. QED.

**2. The claim is true.**

We show a proof sequence that ends with the required statement:

1. $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$ - Axiom 3
2. $(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow(\gamma\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta))$ - Axiom 1 where $A=(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$ and $B=\gamma$
3. $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)\rightarrow(\gamma\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta))$ - NMP (1,2)

**3. The claim is true.**

Proving 4 will imply that 3 is true if $T=\emptyset$:

We need to prove that if $T\vdash_NA$ **then** $T\vdash_{CPL}A$. We show by structural induction.

**Base:** if A is an Axiom or an assumption then it's true by default.

**Induction step:** A is obtained from $(B\rightarrow C),(C\rightarrow D)$ where $A=(B\rightarrow D)$. By the induction hypothesis, $T\vdash_{CPL}(B\rightarrow C)$ and $T\vdash_{CPL}(C\rightarrow D)$.

it's true that $(\alpha\rightarrow\beta),(\beta\rightarrow\gamma)\vdash_{CPL}(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)$ (I leave the proof of this to you).

So we get that $(B\rightarrow C),(C\rightarrow D)\vdash_{CPL}(B\rightarrow D)$ which is $(B\rightarrow C),(C\rightarrow D)\vdash_{CPL}A$. QED.

**4. The claim is true.**

Proved in 3.

Comment: I am not completely convinced that your proof of 3&4 is by structural induction. It seems to me to be by induction on the lengths of $N$-proofs. [I would understand "structural induction" to be on the complexity of the formula $A$ and it seems to me that $A=B\to D$ might be very simple compared with $B\to C$ and $C\to D$ (with $C$ some huge formula).]

Comment: @ancientmathematician To be honest I derived this proof from a claim that my lecturer proved which is similar to this. He proved it by structural induction. I don't know what is induction on the lengths of $N$-proofs  and didn't learn anything about it so I assume that the term structural induction is the true term here.

Comment: OK, all I am saying is that what you know about $B\to C$ and $C\to D$ is that in the $N$-system they have shorter proofs than $A=B\to D$ does. So induction on the lengths of proof will work. What does bug me about this is that both 3 & 4 appear to be true for exactly the same reason: that makes it a very odd question to set.

Comment: Ah, I now understood what you're talking about, you may know more things than me so if you are sure that it's an induction on the lengths I can change it to this. What really interests me is for the question to be true. So if you're sure please tell me so I change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to answer the questions that were given to you, but I will criticize your answer ... and in particular your reasoning:

> ***What I think:*** I think that without any assumptions we can't use NMP at all, therefore we can tell that 1, 2, 4 are false and only 3 is true.

No. This does not work.

First of all, notice that for 1., there *is* an assumption: for 1, the question is whether you can derive $\alpha \to \gamma$ if you assume $\gamma \to (\alpha \to \beta)$. So your reasoning does not work for 1. So maybe 1 is True

Second, and more importantly, in these axiom systems, you can at any point write down any instantiation of any of the axioms.  And given that, you can derive other things.  In other words, you can derive things from nothing. Simple example:

$A \to (B \to A)  \ Axiom \ 1$

Done.  And there!  I just derived something without any assumptions. Indeed, I just showed that $\vdash_{N} A \to (B \to A)$

With that, your reasoning also does not work for 2. So maybe 2 is True.

Likewise, I assume that you said that 3 is True since the antecedent cannot be True, but since $\vdash_N \alpha$ *can* be True just fine, 3 can still be False.

And finally, I don't see how your argument would show 4 to be False: if you say that we can't derive anything in $N$ at all, then 4 shoukld be True, rather than False. But if you dsay that if we have a setof assumpotions $T$ from which we can derive $\alpha$, then why shouldn't we also be able to derive $\alpha$ from $T$ in $CPL$? Your reasoning does nothing towards answering that question.

Again, I am not going to answer the questions put to you ... I would like you to do some more thinking about these questions yourself first, and see if you can come up with some other answers or thoughts before I give any further feedback.

Comment: Well, actually I succeeded in the end to solve 2,3,4 which appeared to be true. However, about 1 I don't think that it's true so I tried to provide proof of why it's not but didn't really write a decent proof for this so if you can provide me with one so I can post my full answer.

Comment: @CSStudent  I'll readily agree with 3 and 4 being true:  N is a sound system, so anything that N is able to derive will in fact logically, follow, and since CPL is complete,, CPL can therefore derive it as well.  2 is a good bit more tricky ... you say you think it's true?  Maybe you can add your reasoning/proof to your post? As for 1 ... that one is of course not an actual logical implication, and since N is sound, N is not able to derive this. So 1 is indeed false.

Comment: Please see this photo, I couldn't write the answer properly in the comments so I wrote it and took a screenshot of it: https://ibb.co/bKfWtvv

Comment: @CSStudent Yes, totally works! Good job